# e constant integration

Tags: integration

The integration of a constant is the constant itself plus some other "constant"

$\int{e^xdx}=e^x+C$

So, the $\int{e^{5x}dx}$ must be:

$$e^{5x}dx=e^{5x}+C$$

This is true if e here is a constant, generally expressing Euler constant: 2.7182...

**Am I right?**

I run the integral with Wolfram Alpha, this is the result:

$$\frac{e^{5x}}{5}+C$$

**Is this happen because Wolfram Alpha do not understand e as a constant?**

Comment: Hint: If you take the derivative of your solution, do you get back the original integral? What do you get if you take the derivative of the WA expression?

Comment: $e^{5x}$ is not a constant! It varies according to $x!

Comment: You are missing the chain rule part of having your function that could be re-written as $e^xe^xe^xe^xe^x$ which if you take the derivative will be $5e^{5x}$ and that 5 has to be canceled out and thus the reason for the 1/5 factor from Wolfram Alpha that you don't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int e^{ax}dx = \frac{1}{a} e^{ax} + C$ . Mathematica is correct

Comment: But, *e* here is the Euler constant? Really a just like to confirm that it is valid for any *e* with constant value.

Comment: Yes, it is the Euler constant.

Comment: $e^{f(x)}$ is NOT a constant.  It is only constant if $f(x)=1$.  The reason is that you have to abide by the chain rule.  In the case where $f(x)=x, f'(x)=1.$  If in the case of the example, $f(x)=5x, f'(x)=5$.  This applies to integration as well, so that is why you get $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: The question here was whether $e$ was the Euler constant, not whether $e^{f(x)}$ is a constant. Since $b^{ax} = e^{axlnb}$, the antiderivative formula would be correct in substance for any "$e$" with this modification.

Answer (score 2):

"The integration of a constant is the constant itself plus some other "constant" "

Is this true?

$\int 4 dx=4x\neq 4+C$

Therefore, it is not true.

Also $\frac d{dx} e^x$ can be thought of like this: Take the derivative of $e^x$, which is $e^x$, and then using the chain rule, take the derivative of $x$, which would give you $e^x (1)=e^x$.

In your example $\frac d{dx} e^{5x}=e^{5x}(5)=5e^{5x}$ by similar logic.

Also note that $e^x$ is not a constant. This is because depending on the value of $x$, its value changes. In a constant, no matter what $x$ value I sub in, it should remain the same. (Example: Given $f(x)=3$, then $f(1)=f(56)=f(9999)=f(0.45)=f(-9)=3)$. Try graphing it; a constant will have a graph that is a horizontal line.

-- 
Edit: Fixing antiderivative

Answer (score 1):

No this happens because the primitive of $e^{5x}$ is $\frac{e^{5x}}{5}$. This comes from the general formula $(f\circ g)'=g'*(f'\circ g)$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that:

$$\int e^{nx}\ dx=n^{-1}e^{nx}+C$$

Remember the chain rule?